# C++ шаблон факториала не работает

Tags: c++, c++17

Написал шаблон - компилируется, запускается и при попытке ввода слетает

```
import std.core;

//#include <iostream>
//#include <functional>

using namespace std;

//========================
template<typename T>
T factorial(T t)
{
    function<T(T)> fact = [&fact](T t)  {return t < 2 ? 1 : t * fact(t - 1);    };
    return 0;
}

//===========================
int main()
{
    char* buff{};

    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl << ">>> ";
    cin >> buff;

    auto n = atoi(buff);
    auto m = atof(buff);

    cout << "n! = " << factorial(n) << endl;
    cout << "m! = " << factorial(m) << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `char buff[...]` как минимум. Или как-нибудь по-другому выделите память.

Comment: А что тут собственно должно работать? Я не вижу чтобы эта лямбда где-то вызывалась.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Должно быть - return fact(t);

Comment: Интересно, что если модуль заменить на включения, то не компилируется.

Answer (score 0):

В коде было две ошибки:

1) не выделялась память под ввод данных buff, только создавался указатель
вариант решения:

char buff[20] - негибкий вариант, но для факториала хватит

string buff - вариант более универсальный

2) в функции не было вызова лямбды fact.

Ниже привёл работающий код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T factorial(T t)
{
    function<T(T)> fact = [&fact](T t)  {return t < 2 ? 1 : t * fact(t - 1);    };
    return fact(t);
}

int main()
{
    string buff;

    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl << ">>> ";
    cin >> buff;

    auto n = atoi(buff.data());
    auto m = atof(buff.data());

    cout << "n! = " << factorial(n) << endl;
    cout << "m! = " << factorial(m) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, Уже было решено - внизу есть ответ.